# Using Animation Node to get modified mesh

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm currently using Animation Nodes to check a mesh and see if any vertices lie within that mesh. This all works well. However if I am doing an animation and modify an object using armatures only the original mesh is seen by Animation Nodes, not the modified mesh. The original object is parented to the armatures using "Armature Deform with Automatic Weights" . Is there a way in Animation Nodes to get the modified mesh into Animation Nodes rather than the original mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Check *"use modifiers"* in the *"mesh object input"* node:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank You @lemon